# Distributions of Quadratic form of a normal random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, multivariate-normal-distribution, moment-generating-function, quadratic-form

I am looking for ways to prove that the moment generating function of $X'AX$ given that $X \sim N(\vec{\mu}, \vec{\Sigma})$ and $A$ is symmetric is defined as:

$$M_{X'AX}(\vec{t})= \frac{1}{|I-2tA\Sigma|^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mu'[I-(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}]\Sigma^{-1}\mu} $$

I found similar texts stating this property but without a proof. But usually I have to show that $A \Sigma$ is symettric idempotent and would already know that $Y'AY$ is non central chi square.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916#442916

Comment: You should reference or link the texts where you saw this.

Comment: One answer is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262604/what-is-the-moment-generating-function-of-the-generalized-multivariate-chi-squ/318908#318908  but there the mgf is very different in form.

Comment: Answered this question with Graybill as reference (Man, the epub on genlib sucks). You guys can PM me for the answer if needed.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks for the links but most of it are unhelpful and even deviated me from the answer. The answer just really required bruteforcing matrix multiplications and kerneling.

Answer (score 5):

I am quite sure @kjetil b halvorsen's answer at [What is the moment generating function of the generalized (multivariate) chi-square distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262604/what-is-the-moment-generating-function-of-the-generalized-multivariate-chi-squ/318908#318908) reduces to the expression of MGF in this post on simplification.

A direct proof is not difficult either when $\Sigma$ is assumed to be positive definite.

The proof simply relies on the fact that for a symmetric positive definite matrix $B$, we have from the multivariate normal density

$$\int_{\mathbb R^p}\exp\left[-\frac12(x-\mu)' B^{-1}(x-\mu)\right] dx=(2\pi)^{p/2}(\det B)^{1/2}$$

Or,

$$\int_{\mathbb R^p}\exp\left[-\frac12 x' B^{-1}x+\mu' B^{-1}x-\frac12 \mu' B^{-1}\mu\right] dx=(2\pi)^{p/2}(\det B)^{1/2}$$

Taking $b'=\mu' B^{-1}$, this is same as

$$\int_{\mathbb R^p}\exp\left[-\frac12x' B^{-1}x+b' x\right]dx=(2\pi)^{p/2}(\det B)^{1/2}\exp\left(\frac12 b' B b\right) \tag{*}$$

For symmetric $A$,

\begin{align}
M_{X' A X}(t)&=E\left[e^{tX' AX}\right]
\\&=\frac1{(2\pi)^{p/2}(\det \Sigma)^{1/2}}\int_{\mathbb R^p} \exp(tx' Ax)\cdot \exp\left[-\frac12(x-\mu)' \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\right] dx
\\\\&=\frac{\exp(-\frac12 \mu'\Sigma^{-1}\mu)}{(2\pi)^{p/2}(\det \Sigma)^{1/2}}\int_{\mathbb R^p} \exp\left[-\frac12 x'(I-2tA\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}x+\mu'\Sigma^{-1}x\right] dx
\end{align}

We have $(I-2tA\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}=\Sigma^{-1}-2tA$, which is assumed positive definite (it is already symmetric) for sufficiently small $|t|$. The MGF is now precisely of the form $(*)$.

Taking $B=(\Sigma^{-1}-2tA)^{-1}=\Sigma(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}$ and $b'=\mu'\Sigma^{-1}$ finally gives

$$M_{X'AX}(t)=(\det(I-2tA\Sigma))^{-1/2}\exp\left\{-\frac12 \mu'[I-(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}]\Sigma^{-1}\mu \right\}\,,$$

whenever the MGF exists. This also generalizes @whuber's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/478628/119261).