# Multivariate Normal Quadratic MGF: Eigendecomposition to Matrix form

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition, moment-generating-function, quadratic-form

> If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ is a multivariate normal, then the quadratic $X^TAX$ has moment generating function
>
> $$M_{X^TAX}(t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(I - 2tA\Sigma)}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mu'[I-(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}]\Sigma^{-1}\mu\right), \tag{1}$$
>
> where $A$ symmetric and $\Sigma$ positive definite.

From the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262604/what-is-the-moment-generating-function-of-the-generalized-multivariate-chi-squ/318908#318908), a nice way of showing this is looking at the Eigendecomposition. That is,

$$X^TAX = \sum_i \lambda_iX_i^2, \quad\quad X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)~~\text{iid}.$$

Then, letting $Y_i := \mu_i + \sigma_iZ_i$, where $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, we get that for $t < 1/2$ the m.g.f. for any $i$ is

$$M_{Y_i}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2t\lambda_i\sigma_i^2}}\exp\left(\frac{\mu_i^2t\lambda_i}{1 - 2t\lambda_i\sigma_i^2}\right).$$

Hence, we arrive at the equation stated in the link, more-or-less:

$$
\begin{align}
M_{X^TAX}(t) &= \prod_{i} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2t\lambda_i\sigma_i^2}}\exp\left(\frac{\mu_i^2t}{1 - 2t\lambda_i\sigma_i^2}\right) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(I - 2tA\Sigma)}}\exp\left(\sum_i \frac{\mu_i^2t\lambda_i}{1 - 2t\lambda_i\sigma_i^2}\right). \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

**My question:** I can't seem to work out how to go from the exponential in $(2)$ back to the exponential in $(1)$, i.e. how do we get

$$\exp\left(\sum_i \frac{\mu_i^2t\lambda_i}{1 - 2t\lambda_i\sigma_i^2}\right) = \cdots = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mu'[I-(I-2tA\Sigma)^{-1}]\Sigma^{-1}\mu\right).$$

I'm sure I'm missing some obvious linear algebra fact about the matrix decomposition here?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing your problem, but your notation seems confusing to me in that $X_i$ and $\mu_i$ seem to be used with two different meanings, i.e. refering to both the original variable, and the eigendecomposition one.